# Khronos locale error: please load locale "en" before using it

Tags: angular

Following datepicker input works well in my local,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="myModel" value="{{ myFilterValue | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}" bsDatepicker>
```

But I have the following error in the development server:

> Khronos locale error: please load locale "en" before using it

I tried to add a config, but didn't work.

```
[bsConfig]='{locale: "en"}'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In Component, try to import the locale file

```
import { BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
constructor(private _localeService: BsLocaleService) {
  this._localeService.use('engb');
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried 'en', which also didn't work.